# conanfile.py should use currently cloned source files

Tags: conan

I have a project that contains source files and conanfile.py.
All the examples of conanfile.py show to clone source files from a repository and then build them, but in my case cloning is a waste of time as the source files are together with the conanfile.py file.

How can I define conanfile.py to use currently cloned source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, read https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_repo.html

The magic is under [exports_sources](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#exports-sources). It will copy all files listed (or matched) on that attribute, then, Conan will copy to your Conan cache, so you can build without clone.